# Google Sheets: Split row value and count each part

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

## My Problem

I have a survey result with a checkbox question in which more than one answer could be checked. The results are given in a single column, separated by a `|` sign.

[image]
I would like to run a count `QUERY` to grade answers by popularity. The expected output for this example is something like (numbers made up):

```
AWS 20
GCP 5
Pizza racks 1
Azure 1
...
```

## What Have I Tried

- `SPLIT`, but then the count spans multiple rows
- Exporting to CSV and some Python-foo, but it's manual and error-prone

## My Question

**How can I `QUERY` COUNT a row which with one or more values in each cell, separated by a delimiter?**

Comment: Updated question with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using join and split - and all in one function with an array literal for display:

```
=arrayformula({UNIQUE(transpose(split(join(" | ",A1:A), " | ",false))), if(istext(UNIQUE(transpose(split(join(" | ",A1:A), " | ",false)))),countif(transpose(split(join(" | ",A1:A), " | ",false)),UNIQUE(transpose(split(join(" | ",A1:A), " | ",false)))),)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",1,TRIM(SPLIT(A1:A4,"|"))),"")),"Select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc",0))
```

- Typical JOIN/SPLIT Combo to separate them all to unique rows
- QUERY to find  and sort the count on the newly created array